# Date created doesn't work but the hard coded does

Tags: powershell, date

I´m trying to consume an api with two dates: startDate and endDate, when I use harcoded endDate the program works, but when I try to use a date that I create it doesn´t

```
$date = Get-Date 
$year = $date.year
$month = $date.Month
$startDate2 = $year.ToString() + "-" + $month.ToString() +  "-" + 01 + "T00:00:00.000-00:00"
$startDate = "2020-5-1T00:00:00.000-00:00"
$endDate2 = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
$toAdd = ".205-07:00"
$endDate2 = $endDate2 + $toAdd
#2019-06-23T09:07:21.205-07:00
Write-Host $endDate2

#Armar el url con las dos fechas
$url_api2 = "https://api.mypurecloud.com/api/v2/billing/reports/billableusage?startDate=" + $startDate2 +"&endDate=" + `
$endDate2
```

Both look the same in structure:
Hardcoded:
2019-06-23T09:07:21.205-07:00
Created
2020-05-29T15:23:48.000-00:00

The api documentation says that this must be the format
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

It comes like this
2020-05-29T16:58:37.SSSZ

So I manipulate de final part to remove the letters

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ISO 8601. Try this.

```bsh
Get-Date -Format o
```

[Round-trip specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip)

You shouldn't need the `$toAdd` variable then.